# Can't ping docker IPv6 container

Tags: docker, ipv6

I ran docker daemon for using it with global IPv6 for containers:

```
docker daemon --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6="xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64"
```

After it I ran docker container:

```
docker run -d --name my-container some-image
```

It successfully got Global IPv6 address( I checked by `docker inspect my-container`). But I can't to ping my container by this ip:

```
Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

But I can successfully ping `docker0` bridge by it's IPv6 address. 
Output of `route -n -6` contains next lines:

```
    Destination                     Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
    xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64         ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
    xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64         ::                         U    1024 0     0 docker0
    fe80::/64                        ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
```

`docker0` interface has global IPv6 address:

```
inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64 Scope:Global
```

`xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::` everywhere is the same, and it's global IPv6 address of my `eth0` interface

Does docker required something additional configs for accessing my containers via IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming IPv6 in your guest OS is properly configured probably you are pinging the container not from host OS, but outside and network discovery protocol is not configured. Other hosts does not know if your container is behind of your host. I'm doing this after start of container with IPv6 (in host OS) (in ExecStartPost clauses of Systemd .service file)

1. /usr/sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.conf.*interface_name*.proxy_ndp=1
2. /usr/bin/ip -6 neigh add proxy $(docker inspect --format {{.NetworkSettings.GlobalIPv6Address}} *container_name*) dev *interface_name*"

Beware of IPv6: docker developers say in replies to bug reports they do not have enough time to make IPv6 production-ready in version 1.10 and say nothing about 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

Mb you use wrong ping command. For ipv6 is ping6.

```
$ ping6 2607:f0d0:1002:51::4
```